# Why the interface of my program is fit in eclipse emulator but not fit in my N1?

Tags: android

Why interface of program is fit in eclipse emulator but not fit in my N1 and Liquid? 
How to solve it?

Comment: Can you post your AVD settings?

Comment: Target: Android 2.1-update1 (API Level 7)  Skin:HVGA  SD Card:512M  hw.lcd.density: 160

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot tell you "how to solve it" specifically, since we did not write your user interface. [Here is the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on supporting multiple screen sizes.

Bear in mind that your AVD is different than your test hardware. Your N1 and Liquid are WVGA800 high-density screens. Your AVD is a HVGA medium-density screen. You might consider making a WVGA800 AVD for your emulator, if you wish to test using the emulator.